# Getting Mesibo connection status 6 and 7

Tags: android, mesibo, chatsdk

When initializing Mesibo **I am getting the following error for existing users** (by existing users I mean old users of the app)

```
    MesiboJNI: E(0710-133818-418)(4810): SSL connect negotiation error -1
D/Kamal: Connection Status: 7
    Mesibo Status: 7
D/Kamal: Connection Status: 6
    Mesibo Status: 6
```

But f**or new users, it is working fine.**
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely your old user token has expired. If that's not the case, please share logs and user details as requested here https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/support/ If details are confidential, send us a support email

Comment: First of all Thanks@mesibo to such a quick response. Kindly help me with How to check that the old user token has expired?

Comment: Send us a token and we will try to tell you unless it is cleaned up. Send us an email. Don't share your token here. When you create a token, there is an expiry, default is 1 year. Also, if your services were discontinued, mesibo cleans up tokens after a few days.

Comment: Okay, I'm sharing the token on the support mail. And could you please guide how to create a new token or refresh it for an existing user?

Comment: Please refer here - https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/

Comment: Thanks, @mesibo will update you. I think the most likely second case is creating the issue.

Comment: @mesibo You can post this as the answer. I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your old user token has expired. If that's not the case, please share logs and user details as requested here mesibo.com/documentation/faq/support If details are confidential, send us a support email